# Is it possible to install dotnet core on macOS without using root access?

Tags: .net-core

I was thinking of playing with dotnet core, but both the Homebrew cask installers and the one provided by MicroSoft require administrator access? I normally don't install packages as root, and so was wondering if there is a way to install dotnet core without root access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download the macOS binaries (`.tar.gz` file) from the [.NET Core download page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core), unpack it to a directory and set your `PATH` environment variable to include the directory you extracted the contents to.